# I am not able to import to class in different module in android studio

Tags: android

I created two modules in single android project, named it x and y.

1.Module x has a class A (Package: com.example.x) which can generate apk
2.Module y has a class B (Package: com.example.y) which is library type module
Now I want to import class A in the class B, for which I wrote the statement mentioned below in class B

```
import com.example.x.A;
```

I Now, A is not recognized by android

I also tried like adding dependencies in `build.gradle`
like this

```
dependencies {
        implementation project(':y')
        // other dependencies
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already added module Y in side build.gradle file of Module X in order to access the classes of Module X, like wise just add Module X in build.gradle file of module Y , so that you could access the files in Module X in Module Y.

Open the build.gradle file of Module Y and add module X. Like :

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':x')
    // other dependencies
}
```

Each module has it's own `build.gradle` file. See below pic:
[image]

Comment: but module y is library type module it has no `build.gradle` file

Comment: Why not bro ? See my post.